# Determining call hierarchy of PL/SQL procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am working on some old PL/SQL code and I want to display the call hierarchy like I would have for Eclipse and Java code.

For instance, if I have the following code:

```
create or replace package body pkgA as 
  procedure foobar is begin
    lambda(1);
  end;

  procedure lambda(a NUMBER) is begin
    pkgB.test();   
  end;
end pkgA;
/
create or replace package body pkgB as 
  procedure test is begin
    select 1 from dual;
  end;
end pkgB;
/
```

I'd like to have this tree:

1. `pkgB.test`

   1. `pkgA.lambda`

      1. `pkgA.foobar`

Note: I am using Toad 9, but I did not see such feature (well, unless I need to look for to something like the referential tree for foreign keys).

Beside, I'm looking more for a static analysis than a dynamic, or something implying that I execute the code.

Comment: PL/SQL is likely to miss such a tool. Please give [PL/SQL Hierarchical Profiler](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e41502/adfns_profiler.htm#ADFNS023) a try. You have to execute the code though.

Comment: [PL/Scope](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADFNS/adfns_plscope.htm#ADFNS022) can do this.  I don't have time to create a specific example right now, maybe someone else can.

Comment: For infomation on PL/Scope [read this article](http://www.oracle.com/au/products/database/o50plsql-165471.html).

Comment: DBMS_DEBUG.PRINT_BACKTRACE

Comment: You can use [dbms_utility.format_Call_stack](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_util.htm#i1003874) inside your program units where you require a stack trace

Comment: True, this is good for debugging, but this one implies executing the code, which is not static analysis (which I need)..

Comment: Updated link to @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica URL https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/zoom-in-on-your-code

Answer (score 1):

I think the better package procedure to call for this is: dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace

So you'd use DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace);
I put those in my exception handler for testing all the time (to the point where I have a code template that drops it in).  I also output the instruction:

So it returns results like this:

```
EXCEPTION IN aeo_misc_tools.cursor_to_listV2 - -900: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
EXCEPTION IN my test script - -900: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
Error stack at top level:
ORA-06512: at "AEO.AEO_MISC_TOOLS", line 805
ORA-06512: at line 8
```

It won't format the error in a tree format, as you specified, but it gets the job done so you can find the error on the correct line.

Comment: It's not a complete solution, it would be great if it was possible to do it fully automatically. Just imagine you faced with a blood Enterprise legacy code where one package consists of 60k rows of plsql code.

Comment: Looks like `UTL_CALL_STACK` is a little more flexible, and there is a good overview at https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/utl-call-stack-12cr1

Comment: @MarkStewart - Thanks for the link but I actually see LESS useful output from the UTL_CALL_STACK routines referenced in that article than I do from DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE. The article example shows you should see ALL call levels, but I only see the first and last. The other examples gave me similar, limited results. I confirmed our version and have no clue why I see less.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the called hierarchy of Visual-Expert, this tools analyse the PL code and show you the call function

[image: Called hierarchy of PL code]

Answer (score 0):

It might not be the best solution, but I have figured out by using PL/Scope recursively. Hope it can help anyone in need. :)

```sql
create or replace procedure getAllChildCall ( definitionName in char, packageName in char, callLevel in number )
as
begin
    for rec in (
        with package_tree as (
            select * from all_identifiers
            where object_name = packageName and object_type = 'PACKAGE BODY'
        )
        select distinct 
            name, signature, type, line,
            usage, usage_id, usage_context_id 
        from package_tree
        start with (name = definitionName and usage = 'DEFINITION')
        connect by prior usage_id = usage_context_id
    ) loop
        if rec.usage = 'CALL' and rec.name not in (
        'DEBUG', 'SQLERRM', 'COMMITRECORD', 'ISNOTZERO', 'NVL', 'TRUNC', 'ROUND') then
            dbms_output.put_line(LPAD(' ', 2*callLevel, ' ') || rec.name);
            getallchildcall(rec.name, packageName, callLevel+1);
        end if;
    end loop;
end;
/

set serveroutput on

declare
    callLevel number;
begin
callLevel := 1;

dbms_output.put_line('start traverse the package child call graph...');
getAllChildCall(upper('YOUR_PROCEDURE_NAME'), upper('YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME'), callLevel);

end;
```